# Oracle multiple REPLACE options in REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: regex, oracle, search, replace, regexp-replace

I have a requirement to replace a part of the string with a new value.
Eg: An ITEM ([loc]-[number]) where both LOC and NUMBER are numeric fields.

I have a list of items and I need to replace ITEM's starting with LOC 111, 222, 333 to 444, 555, 666 respectively.

I tried REGEXP_REPLACE function but it allows multiple search patterns and a single replace pattern. Is there an option to allow multiple replace patterns as well?

Eg:

```
select regexp_replace('111-123456','111|222|333','444|555|666',1,1) from dual
```

Is the above possible?

Comment: No way, I do not know a regex flavor that will allow using alternatives in a literal replacement string.

Comment: @stribizhev....Thanks for that.. Is there an approach to do this instead of having multiple REPLACE functions?

Comment: There are non-regex way to do that in different programming languages, like using callback functions, match evaluators, delegates, etc. I do not know of an analogical solution for your case.

Comment: @stribizhev... Thanks.. I need to resort to typical DECODE statement and SUBSTR function then to achieve my results...